# How to fix the "HD-Frontend" error in bluestack?

Tags: android

Whenever I start my bluestack, they gave a error like `HD-Frontend <vm-name>`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click & hit restart your bluestack from taskbar...will fix the problem